# show custom menu in page tpl file

Tags: theming, routes

```
<?php if (isset($custom_links)) { ?>
<div id="secondaryNav"><?php print theme('links', $custom_links) ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I've create a custom menu (machine name: menu-secondary-menu). And I want to display it in page.tpl. My condition is to show this this menu only if it has links added. I searched and found the above code. Please help me in customizing to my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Enter the machine name of the menu you want to show.
$menu_name = 'main-menu';
// Check if there are any menu items in it.
if (count(menu_navigation_links($menu_name))):
?>
<div id="secondaryNav">
  <?php print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links($menu_name), 'attributes' => array('id' => $menu_name, 'class'=> array('links', 'inline')))); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```